# add a subcollection under each document that resulted from geofirestore query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I queried 'users/userid/pros' firestore collection using cloud functions geofirestore, and I get a few specific documents('users/userid/pros/proid') from the query. Now, I want to add a new 'notifs' collection subsequently under each of these specific documents I get from the query. Here is my code to implement that functionality.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var GeoFirestore = require('geofirestore').GeoFirestore;

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(firestore);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document("users/{userId}/clients/{client}")
.onCreate(async snapshot => {
    const clientfield = snapshot.data().field;
    const clientgeopoint = snapshot.data().g.geopoint;

    const geocollection = geofirestore.collectionGroup('pros');
    const query = geocollection.near({center: clientgeopoint, radius: 
10}).where('field', '==', clientfield);
   
    await query.get().then( querySnapshot => {
        
        querySnapshot.forEach(async doc => {
                   
            await doc.ref.collection('notifs').add({
                'field': clientfield, ... });
    
            });
         }).catch ((error) =>
            console.log(error)
        );
 })
```

But this code gives me an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined' on cloud functions console. How can I fix my code in order to add 'notifs' collection right under each of these specific documents like in the picture? Thanks.

Comment: How is your `query` defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "to add 'notifs' collection **at the end** of these specific documents"?

Comment: Thanks Renaud. That means I'd like to leave these specific documents as they are in the path and just add `notifs` collections subsequently to each of the documents, not create `notifs` collection from the firestore root, showing `users/userId/pros/proId` in Italic.

Comment: `@Frank` Thanks, Frank. I added my `query` above. Please check it and give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to fetch the querysnapshot data wrong. From Muthu's reply it should look like this

```
let querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).collection('pros').get();
querySnapshot.then(querySnapshot => {
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

    // frame your data here

   await doc.ref.collection('notifs').add({ ... }); 

  });
});
```

If you are going to get the data from your snapshot you need to add the .then() statement after .get to properly reference the query.

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentSnapshot` carries their reference in a field; For `Node.JS - ref` and for `Dart - reference`. You shall use this to perform any action within that document. Assuming the code was written in NodeJS, for creating sub-collection,

```
query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

        // frame your data here

        await doc.ref.collection('notifs').add({ ... });
 
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply MTM, I tried await doc.ref.collection('notifs').add({ //data here}); but I get this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined' on console. What should I do?

Comment: sample snippet: 
`let querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userid).collection('pros').get();

querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    await doc.ref.collection('notifs').add({ ... });
});`

Comment: I edited my question by adding upper part code to show you where my querysnapshot comes from. Querysnapshot here is not from admin.firestore(), but from GeoFirestore(firestore). I think that's why I get this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined'. What do you think?

Comment: haven't worked with GeoFirestore; if your `DocumentSnapshot` is valid then you won't get `'collection' of undefined` error; try to log & debug your data in local.

Comment: My queryDocumentSnapshot is OK because I can see all queryDocumentSnapshot info with command `console.log(doc.**)`. I can't figure out why `.ref` does not have a `.collection()` function.